# Index error when trying to plot from a csv file

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to plot candlestick chart using finplot and csv as source but I am getting the following error:
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4

My code looks like:

```
import finplot as fplt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("2020.csv")

df= df[1000:3000]

fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['OPEN', 'CLOSE', 'HIGH', 'LOW']])
fplt.show()
```

My dataframe structure is like (df.head(10)):

```
                  DATE     OPEN     HIGH      LOW    CLOSE
1000  2020-01-02 09:40  1.11779  1.11780  1.11747  1.11756
1001  2020-01-02 09:41  1.11756  1.11767  1.11743  1.11752
1002  2020-01-02 09:42  1.11753  1.11753  1.11724  1.11724
1003  2020-01-02 09:43  1.11726  1.11728  1.11712  1.11718
1004  2020-01-02 09:44  1.11719  1.11737  1.11717  1.11724
1005  2020-01-02 09:45  1.11724  1.11745  1.11724  1.11744
1006  2020-01-02 09:46  1.11743  1.11744  1.11725  1.11731
1007  2020-01-02 09:47  1.11728  1.11740  1.11728  1.11739
1008  2020-01-02 09:48  1.11738  1.11746  1.11712  1.11712
1009  2020-01-02 09:49  1.11712  1.11731  1.11711  1.11725
```

Do you know how I can get rid of this error? With plottly I used same structure and I didnt had this error.

Answer (score 0):

```
plt.candlestick_ochl(df[['DATE', 'OPEN', 'CLOSE', 'HIGH', 'LOW']])
```

should work (if your date is `pandas.to_datetime()` formatted).